# Using sed to replace words

Tags: text-processing, sed

Is it possible to use sed to replace words, but avoid replacing words that begin with the letters?

For example if I replace man with woman, but women becomes wowoman is it possible to skip woman with sed? Or would you pipe in sed again to remove wo from the beginning of the letters ?

```
sed -i 's/man/woman/g' /usr/share/dict/words | sed 's^wo//'g /usr/share/dict/words
```

which doesn't seem to be working just add another wo on the start.

After reading more on piping grep into sed i tried the following command

```
sudo sed -i 's/man/woman | grep -v 'woman'/g' words1
```

what i am looking to try out is replace all letter that have man with woman

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: also, not sure you want to be using `-i` in this case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only replace "man" if it's a single word:

```
sed -i 's/\bman\b/woman/g' /usr/share/dict/words
```

Comment: after reading on passing grep into sed i tried this command 'sudo sed -i 's/man/woman | grep -v 'woman'/g' words1'  the output of the file is wowoman | grep -v woman

Comment: Please watch your command carefully. ```sed 's/xxx/yyy/g'``` is replacing "xxx" by "yyy". So your command will replace "man" by "wowoman | grep -v woman"